# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - In Sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to move my working website to a subdomain like this

```
 web1.origdomain.com //working laravel
 web2.origdomain.com//working symfony
 web3.origdomain.com//not working plain html5
```

web1 and web2 comes with .htaccess out from the box, while web3 .htaccess is hard coded, meaning a copy paste from some tutorials in Google .Well, web3 is working perfectly in development machine.

```
 localhost:8096
```

Actually, web3 will work in production if I move it in origdomain by simply temporarily tweaking Apache2, something like

```
 origdomain.com
```

This is how I created the web3.conf in Apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web3
    <Directory /var/www/web3/>
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/web3/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/web3/log/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Other subdomains is configured the same way above, but I confused why web3 does not work here.Maybe web3 .htaccess is wrongly configured here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also I am confused the error logs in Apache2

```
 Sun Dec 20 17:36:45.958848 2015] [:error] [pid 4426] [client 124.83.19.163:58938] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ALL_HTTP in /var/www/web3/app/detect.php on line 118
```

Again, web3 will work perfectly if its place as the

```
origdomain.com
```

instead of as subdomain

```
web3.origdomain.com
```

This the structure of web3

```
  web3
    app
        detect.php
    log
    web
        css
        js
        about.php
        index.php
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

How do you solve this?
mode_rewrite enabled already

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve it. This is how I configure web3.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName   web3.origdomain.com
  ServerAlias  web3.origdomain.com

 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 DocumentRoot /var/www/web3
 <Directory "/var/www/web3">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

   .....
   .....
</VirtualHost>
```